# Final Cut Pro: export multiple files

Tags: video, final-cut-pro

I'm checking the documentation but I can't find a solution.
I have imported multiple media (12 .mov files) and I want to export them as h264/mp4. I can do that one by one but I was looking for a way to do it all in once since I have lots of them. If I select all the media I've imported the file->share menu is all greyed out (except for "Add destination").

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly in Compressor if you're doing nothing but converting.

Add all, Select all, right click [any one] Add Outputs, select output format, Start Batch.

[image]

Comment: what is Compressor? Is it already inside Final Cut Pro?

Comment: It's a separate app, but it's what FCP fires off the actual transcoding job to. I was sure when you bought one, you got the other bundled in with it - though I've had mine so long I don't really recall now. Check Applications folder.

Comment: nope, I don't have it..it's a university mac so they installed final cut pro before giving it to me..

Comment: Ah, pity, you're missing out on a lot of potential power when transcoding. idk how you'd do it directly in FCP as a single task, sorry.